# Get nested element value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the html:

```
<div>
     <label>
        <input type='radio' name='a'>
        <span></span>
        <input type='hidden' value='1'>
     </label>
     <label>...
</div>
```

I need to get value of hidden input by click event on label.

I have javascript like this:

```
$('label').live('click', function () {

        var value = $(this).children('input:hidden').val();

    });
```

But this is not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: Well, you have the `value` variable there, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

Comment: Try console.log($(this).children('input:hidden').val()) in Chrome to view the value in console tab

Comment: " BoltClock" this is not relevant what i will do with this value. This is not a question. My problem is to get this value

Answer (score 1):

Works fine:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='radio' name='a'>
        <span></span>
        <input type='hidden' value='1'>
    </label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('label').live('click', function () {  
        var value = $(this).children('input:hidden').val();
        console.log(value);   
    });
</script>
```

Output: 1

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
 Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>


$(function() {
$('label').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).children('input:hidden').val();

});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you absolutely have to, you should avoid `live()` function. Depending on jQuery version, use `bind()`, `click()` or `on()`

But your code works fine, see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U2TY/8/).